# "type" keyword in mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, mongoose

So I am new to Typescript but in the Mongoose library you can define a Schema like the following:

```
const blogSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type: String},
  author: {type: String}
})
```

What does "type" mean here?

Is {type: String} another object assigned to both title and author? Or is it some Typescript syntax?

I looked at Mongoose source code and found that String is a class, but I can't understand what this would mean in the above code --> title: {type: String}

Comment: There's no better reference than official documentation ~ https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#type-key. This has nothing to do with TypeScript; the syntax is exactly the same for regular JavaScript. [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) is a built-in class as are most of the other schema types

Answer (score 1):

Take `title: {type: String}` as an example,
The `type` here is the data defined as `String` type for `title`, which is the data type in Mongo. I am also a novice. This is just my understanding.